# Not able to load Custom fields of Blogs & News in Sitefinity

Tags: c#, sitefinity

After Publish & Hosting the site over virtual Machine, The custom fields which we created inside the Blogs & News module will not be loaded in sitefinity

Answer (score 4):

The metadata of the custom fields is stored in the configuration files - make sure you synced them as well.

Also, the Database needs to be synced so that the new column is added to the table.

Comment: I have synced the database but I think remain with configuration files. Let me check

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks @Veselin Vasilev for the support.

Comment: @AnandThakkar great - please mark the question as Answered